# OpenVpn issue with FTP traffic

Tags: networking, vpn, ftp, routing, openvpn

OpenVpn traffic counter stops to increase when downloading file via ftp.

At the beginning, when downloading file via ftp, everything is as expected, but when some portion of file is downloaded, openvpn counter stops to increase for the left amount of traffic.

All subsequent ftp downloads also do not change openvpn traffic counter. 
After restarting openvpn connection the situation repeats again.

I have configured openvpn to route all traffic throug vpn. This is part of my configuration parameters:

```
client
dev tun

route-nopull
route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4

proto udp

redirect-gateway
```

The routing table looks fine and the `tracert` command to ftp server also goes through vpn. I really do not know why this happens for ftp, since for http it works as expected all the time.

**UPDATE**:
I use Windows 8.1 x64 as OS. 
I get the traffic counters value via openvpn management interface by using `--management ip port` argument.

VPN server I use has api for getting traffic counters values. They also stop to increase when downloading ftp. I tested where packets go using wireshark, and all of them goes through openvpn during ftp download.

Answer (score 1):

There is no traffic counter built into OpenVPN, so you must be using additional software to do the traffic counting.  You should probably provide more detail here.  (Where you are getting tthe traffic counter info from, the OS you are using etc)

FTP is a messy protocol.   I'd postulate that there is an issue related to connection tracking / NAT for the protocol, and that some traffic counting rule is being intercepted before the traffic is hitting the rules associated with OpenVPN.

The problem is almost certainly not related to the OpenVPN configuration, as traffic would not get through if it was wrong.

Comment: thank you for response, I have updated my answer with extra details.